# k2 extra fields translation issue

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-k2

i have an issue that is going to destroy my mind  ... i am not a PHP developer so i can not find any way to solve it...

I am using K2 (v 2.6.2 updated from 2.5.7) for CCK (with alotof custom templates) and Joomfish (2.1.7) deployed on a Joomla 1.5.26 installation.

I was using the following code (in my templates) in order to fetch my individual k2 extra fields by name (K2 2.5.7):

```
$extraFld = array();
if ( $this->item->extra_fields ) {
  foreach ( $this->item->extra_fields as $key=>$extraField ) {
    $extraFld[ $extraField->name ] = $extraField->value;
   }
}
```

and then i was fetching it like this:

```
echo "<li class=\"dinning-cuisine\"><span>" . JText::_('Cuisine') . "</span><br />" . $extraFld['Cuisine'] . "</li>\n";
```

But since version 2.6.2 there is the option to directly fetch an extra field name & val:

$this->item-extraFields->ALIASNAME->name
$this->item-extraFields->ALIASNAME->value

as described in K2 2.6.2 What is new documentation.

The problem is the following:

I have a bi-lingual site in Greek (default) and English locales.

I create an extra field in Default locale "Πεδίο 1" with alias name 'field1'

If i try to translate it the only option i have is to translate its name to lets say 'Extra Field 1' (different than its alias) ...

Then in my custom template if i try to fetch it like:

```
$this->item->extraFields->field1->value
```

only the Greek locale works. In English locale i receive a NULL value!

Any relevant experiences and solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite alot of tests i think that in a multilingual web site, retrieving individual extra field values using their alias name does not work. At least not for Joomla 1.5 ...

The code supposed to be working is:

$this->item-extraFields->ALIASNAME->value

I have a web site with default language 'Greek' and secondary language 'English'.

I have an extra field named in Greek 'Πεδίο 1' with Alias 'field1'.

I have translated this extra field (using Joomfish) in English to 'Field 1'...

If i try to fetch its value using:

$this->item-extraFields->field1->value

the code is working only for default language 'Greek' BUT NOT for English.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

**String:**

```
JText::_('CUISINE') //should always be Capital letters
```

**Translation (language file):**

```
CUISINE=Cuisine
```

I'm not sure which file you are using to translate the string, however seeing as you are adding this code to your template index.php, add the translation string to **en-GB.tpl_tamplatename.ini**

Comment: The problem is not with label (JTEXT::_('Cuisine')) rather with extra field value ... Label is OK!

Comment: I think this is a bug of k2 framework ... The method proposed in the documentation for fecthing individual k2 extra field values gy using their alias does not work in a multilingual site.